# Issues with getting records from azure storage by timestamp interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, timestamp, azure-storage

I got a issue with getting records from azure storage by timestamp interval. Here's my query.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionString"));

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TableName");

string fromDate = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, fromDateTime);
string toDate = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, toDateTime);
string anotherValue = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("AnotherValue", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Value");
string timeCombine = TableQuery.CombineFilters(fromDate, TableOperators.And, toDate);

TableQuery<StorageSPS> query = new TableQuery<StorageSPS>().Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(anotherValue, TableOperators.And, timeCombine));
var data = (await (table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, new TableContinuationToken(), System.Threading.CancellationToken.None))).Results;
```

After executing the query, I get no records at all. Is there anything , that I'm doing wrong. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks very much for Your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmentedasync.aspx) returns a Task of [TableQuerySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj733153.aspx), which contains both the results of this call and a [continuation token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj732896.aspx) to query the next set of results. By design, a single ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync call can return 0 entities (see [Query Timeout and Pagination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx)), but the client can call it again with the continuation token provided. For example;

```
int count = 0;
do
{
    TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity> querySegment =
        await currentTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
    token = querySegment.ContinuationToken;

    foreach (DynamicTableEntity entity in querySegment)
    {
        ++count;
    }
}
while (token != null);
```

Comment: Thanks mate for Your help. It really helped me. Though it's very slow. I know it's because of being not serialized. I will try to think out, what I can to, do get the data little quicker, than it's getting now. Anyway , thanks again pal.

Answer (score 1):

As Serdar said in another comment, a returned segmented result might be empty and you need to issue the query request again with the returned ContinuationToken, until the returned ContinuationToken is null.

Another thing I'd like to mention is, please **avoid** timestamp interval query if possible. Such a query will result in a **whole table scan** in server side. If timestamp interval query is needed usually in your scenario, please consider choosing timestamp as your partition key or row key to optimize the query performance.

Please refer to following posts for table partition key and row key design:

[How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx)

[Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/)